# Can't change column names in pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {'comp_1': {'property_4': 24, 'property_2': 45, 'property_3': 124, 'missing': 39, 'property_1': 16}, 
 'comp_2': {'property_4': 23, 'property_2': 49, 'property_3': 126, 'property_1': 16, 'missing': 38}, 
 'comp_3': {'property_4': 24, 'property_2': 43, 'property_1': 19, 'missing': 30, 'property_3': 116}}
```

When I load it into panda dataframe and try to print it it looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hits, orient='index')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        missing  property_1  property_2  property_3  property_4
comp_1       39          16          45         124          24
comp_2       38          16          49         126          23
comp_3       30          19          43         116          24
```

Now, I want to rename the columns, so I try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hits, orient='index' columns=reversed(['Missing', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']))
```

which yields empty data frame (which I assume because these keys do not exist in dictionary?):

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

If I try this instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hits, orient='index')
columns = reversed(['Missing', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4'])
df.columns=columns
```

columns are renamed by order is not preserved, so each time I run the code the number do not correspond to the column, e.g:

```
        P4  P3   P2  P1  Missing
comp_1  16  24  124  45       39
comp_2  16  23  126  49       38
comp_3  19  24  116  43       30
```

and:

```
        P4  P3  P2   P1  Missing
comp_1  24  16  39  124       45
comp_2  23  16  38  126       49
comp_3  24  19  30  116       43
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow provide keys from the nested dictioary when I load data into dataframe, but I'm not sure how to do it. Or is it something else I need to do?

**Edit:**
I also tried renaming columns with dictionary as follows:

```
df.rename({'missing': 'Missing', 'property_1': 'P1', 'property_2': 'P2', 'property_3': 'P3',
           'property_4': 'P4'})
```

but still old names are shown

Comment: The order of the columns should be irrelevant in your code whenever possible. Columns are named, so they're accessed by name, not order. Just rename them using a dictionary: `df = df.rename({'property_1': 'P1', ...})`. If you want to reorder them, then you can simply use indexing: `df = df[reversed(df.columns)]`

Comment: the `columns` keyword in the `from_dict` method doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't "rename" the columns in a specific order (after all, dictionaries are unordered by "definition".. it only changed in python 3.7+ preserving insertion order), but rather "looks" for which keys to look up in the dictionary you're passing. So, first import your dictionary into a dataframe, and then reorder the columns however you feel more confortable with. Do not "trust" in ordering here; rather, use `rename` method and map with a dict the old names and new names

Comment: I tried renaming as well as suggested by @AlexanderReynolds  but it doesn't change names. I'll edit my question

Comment: You need to reassign back to the original dataframe. Note my comment says `df = df.rename(...)`. Presumably that's the issue, but we'll see with the updated post. Edit: post updated, I believe I'm correct in my assumption.

Comment: Re:edit see my answer on how to use `rename()` correctly.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds you are, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `columns` parameter in `to_dict` only specifies the columns you want to select. For example,

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hits, orient='index', columns=['property_4'])

        property_4
comp_1          24
comp_2          23
comp_3          24
```

Only selects the "property_4" column, ignoring everything else. Of course, this makes sense because dictionaries inherently do not have ordering. Your only option is to rename the keys or rename the columns using `DataFrame.rename()`.

```
cmap = {'property_1': 'P1', 'property_2': 'P2', 'property_3': 'P3', 
        'property_4': 'P4', 'missing': 'Missing'}
df = df.rename(columns=cmap)
df

        P4  P2   P3  Missing  P1
comp_1  24  45  124       39  16
comp_2  23  49  126       38  16
comp_3  24  43  116       30  19
```

Comment: And if OP wants to keep a specific order, they can just index their dataframe in the column order they prefer and reassign.

Comment: Just for the matter of this answer, `dictionaries inherently do not have ordering` might not be true for Python 3.7+, where dicts follow insertion order. (not my point to be annoying, just sharing the news haha).

Comment: @RafaelC No, you're right, it's an important point. For the purpose of discussion though, I did not want to bog down OP with specifics as they very well might not be using 3.6+ and it wouldn't be right to assume as such unless they mentioned it explicitly. Thanks for weighing in!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as @AlexanderReynolds noticed I've missed reassignment part `df = df.rename(...)`. Thanks everyone for the input

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a dict to replace the columns and give you 1:1 mapping.  Adding the in place flag will do it in the existing dataframe, omitting it will give you a new dataframe with a the new column names.

```
df.rename(columns = {
    'property_1': 'P1',
    'property_2': 'P2',
    'property_3': 'P3',
    'property_4': 'P4',
    'missing': 'Missing'
    }, inplace = True)
```

Comment: I would avoid using `inplace` arguments; they're likely to be deprecated in future versions of Pandas; and otherwise, this answer is the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55150313/5087436

Comment: Good to know thanks, and I didn't see that one when I posted, but yea they're the same.